# Private data on PFUser

Tags: swift, security, parse-platform, pfuser

I currently work on a iOS app witch uses Parse.com as backend. I do have the model but I'm a bit concerned about the privacy of "my" users. Since I need the functionality for a user to search for other users to send them invitations, I need the user class to be public but I don't want the email address to be public.

From what I've learned from stackoverflow is that this is a request for years.

My first idea was to add another class with all the private data and just Point to this class. The private class would be ACL secured on object level but I would lose the functionality to reset the users password.

Has anyone found a solution to keep the reset function? Is this something for cloud code?

Answer (score 0):

The User data is not public on Parse. You can't directly do queries for other users.

When you do need to query for user, you explicitly add `useMasterKey` to your query.

Comment: That's not true. You can lock the User class but you loose the availability to query users. Please take a look at the parse dev guid. https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-querying

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. But you should still be able to handle this via a Cloud Function and useMasterKey